# $H^2(G;\mathbb Z) \cong H^1(G;\mathbb {C}^*)$.

Tags: homological-algebra, group-cohomology

$H^2(G;\mathbb Z) \cong H^1(G;\mathbb {C}^*)$. Where $G$ is a finite group and $G$ acts trivially on $\mathbb Z, \mathbb C^*$.

I have really tried hard but still I couldn't solve it , any help will be appreciated.

My attempt:

Universal Coefficient theorem of Group Cohomology states that:

$$ 0 \longrightarrow Ext^{1}_{\mathbb Z}(H_{n-1}(G;\mathbb Z),\mathbb Z) \longrightarrow H^n(G, \mathbb Z) \longrightarrow Hom_{Ab}((H_{n}(G;\mathbb Z),\mathbb Z)\longrightarrow 0 $$
is split exact.

I have tried calculating $H^2(G, \mathbb Z)$ using this and $ H^1(G, \mathbb C^*)$ but nothing has come up.

Then I tried calculating  $ H^1(G,\mathbb {Q/Z})$ but still dead end.
Could anyone please give me atleast a hint.

$\textbf{This is an Exercise in Weibels Homological Algebra Exer 6.1.6}$
Again for any help or hint I am grateful. Thanks!!

Comment: Maybe you can try to use the exponential exact sequence $0 \to \mathbb{Z} \overset{\times 2i\pi}\to \mathbb{C} \overset{\exp}{\to} \mathbb{C}^\ast \to 1$.

Comment: Thank you @AlexL

Comment: So by this we'll have a lomng exact sequence of cohomology $$ ...0 \longrightarrow H^1(G; \mathbb C^*) \longrightarrow H^2 (G; \mathbb Z) \longrightarrow 0 \longrightarrow ...$$

Comment: Certainly $H^1(G, \mathbb C) =0$ but could please give a hint why that is also true for $ H^i(G, \mathbb C) =0\; \forall i > 1 $

Comment: $H^i(G,\Bbb C)$ is $|G|$-torsion, but also torsion free (since $\Bbb C$ is). @DibyaBanerjee

Comment: @ Lord Shark the unknown thank you very much is it possible to give me a reference of this |G| - torsion. I didn't understand the |G| - torsion . Thanks